# View the pdf file & verify contents(text) In Protractor Javascript (IE & chrome)

Tags: javascript, pdf, protractor

Is there a way to retrieve the stream(text) from URL like 'http://www.princexml.com/samples/flyer/flyer.pdf' using javascript(in protractor), process it & get the contents of it either into a variable or text file with out downloading it

Currently I'm able to achieve this by using http.request() as specified in 'http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html' & saving it as a new PDF file, parsing this new file using pdfreader.js and getting it contents. But what i want is to process the buffer which i get it from http.request() & return the contents directly without saving/downloading it and processing the contents.

Comment: Can you share your code @deepak